# Glyphicons and other icon fonts don't show up in Internet Explorer after page refresh

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I'm totally stumped on this problem (the app in question uses Bootstrap and Backbone):

- when you first load the app after logging in the glyphicons and other icon fonts show up on the page fine.
- on subsequent page loads they don't show up at all. But you can log out and log back in and they show up again.
- it only happens in Internet Explorer. Chrome/FF/Safari are fine.
- it doesn't happen if you go to a part of the app that doesn't require authentication

The same part of the app with (top) and without icons (bottom):

[image: with icons]
[image: without icons]

Unfortunately to see the problem it requires authentication so here is that info (you will be redirected to the app):

https://voicethread.com/login/

username: ietest@voicethread.net

pass: orange4

Comment: Debug tools show that the font resource `https://d25wzyo6b5ic8t.cloudfront.net/rev/12dfaed/myvoice/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix` is delivered as `Content-Type: text/plain` – that should be `application/vnd.ms-fontobject` however. Try fixing that first of all, and see if it makes the issue go away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be fixed, as of `/rev/353fe835`.  While not sending the proper MIME type was indeed *a* problem, it didn't appear to be *the* problem.

Instead, the issue appeared to be the `no-cache` headers.  When not allowing cache, IE was not displaying those glyph icons in certain cases.  Related posts: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13415073/on-ie-css-font-face-works-only-when-navigating-through-inner-links/13424799#13424799), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7748140/font-face-eot-not-loading-over-https), and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7748140/font-face-eot-not-loading-over-https/18200121#18200121).