# Font awesome not loading first time

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, fonts, font-awesome, custom-font

We are facing a strange problem with font awesome, It is not loading first time and not even after refreshing the page. But it will load correctly if we move to a different page in the application(MVC5, Bootstrap, font awesome).This is issue is happening only with IE. We are able to narrow down the issue and it happens only when we disable caching by adding these lines in web.config. If remove these lines then it will work(as per InfoSec policy, we have to disable caching).

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="SAMEORIGIN"/>
    <!-- HTTP 1.1. -->
    <add name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />        
    <!-- HTTP 1.0. -->
    <add name="Pragma" value="no-cache" />        
    <!-- Proxies. -->
    <add name="Expires" value="0" />        
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021946/add-mime-mapping-in-web-config-for-iis-express or http://codingstill.com/2013/01/set-mime-types-for-web-fonts-in-iis/

Comment: Yes, We have added required mime types and font will work if we move to another page in the application with same Layout.cshtml where we added all the css links.

Comment: Live link is possible?

Comment: Application is hosted in intranet and not available outside :(

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13415073/on-ie-css-font-face-works-only-when-navigating-through-inner-links

Comment: lol @ https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedbackdetail/view/992569/font-face-not-working-with-internet-explorer-and-http-header-pragma-no-cache