# Remove "Vary" Header for eot fonts with Spring 5.2

Tags: spring-mvc

Currently I'm upgrading some Spring MVC components from Spring 5.1.12 to Spring 5.2.2. Something that is changed in Spring 5.2 is [Cors Handling](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-5.x#upgrading-to-version-52). This impacts the loading of the fonts in IE9. Caching fonts in combination with IE9 is [kind of unstable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13415073/on-ie-css-font-face-works-only-when-navigating-through-inner-links).

What exactly happens is that after te upgrade 3 response headers are added

```
Vary: Origin 
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
```

I tried to change the CORS policy with

Existing code:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    ..
    registry.addResourceHandler("/fonts/**").addResourceLocations("/fonts/");
    ..
}
```

Added

```
 @Override
 public void addCorsMappings(final CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/fonts/**").
        allowedOrigins("http://domain2.com").allowedMethods("PUT", "DELETE").allowedHeaders("header1", "header2", "header3").exposedHeaders("header1", "header2")

        .allowCredentials(false).maxAge(3600);
 }
```

But this doesn't impact the headers. How do I remove these headers for eot files, so IE9 keeps showing them correctly?