# How to get around Internet Explorer 11 ignoring my font-face due to cache-control headers?

Tags: css, angular, azure, internet-explorer

**Problem:**

IE11 does not use my Roboto font-face or my Material Icon font-faces. I've narrowed the issue down to the cache-control. When I remove the following from my **web.config**, IE11 displays my fonts and icons just like any other browser. I found this solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/37270083/10316412

```
<add name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache" />
<add name="Pragma" value="no-cache" />
```

However, I would much prefer not to remove this. Our security scan requires that we have no-cache. We are also not supposed to link to external fonts/icons due to subresource integrity... which is why I have downloaded the fonts and icons into my assets folder.

**My Question:**

Why does the cache-control affect my fonts not loading? How can I get around this? Can I specify there to be no cache-control headers for just my assets folder?

font-face code for reference:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  src: url(./assets/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf);
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Roboto-Light";
  src: url(./assets/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Light.ttf);
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Roboto-Medium";
  src: url(./assets/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Medium.ttf);
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Roboto-Bold";
  src: url(./assets/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Bold.ttf);
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Roboto-Italic";
  src: url(./assets/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Italic.ttf);
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Material Icons";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(assets/google-icons/font/MaterialIcons-Regular.eot); /* For IE6-8 */
  src: local("Material Icons"), local("MaterialIcons-Regular"),
    url(assets/google-icons/font/MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf) format("truetype"),
    url(assets/google-icons/font/MaterialIconsOutlined-Regular.otf) format("opentype"),
    url(assets/google-icons/font/MaterialIconsRound-Regular.otf) format("opentype"),
    url(assets/google-icons/font/MaterialIconsSharp-Regular.otf) format("opentype"),
    url(assets/google-icons/font/MaterialIconsTwoTone-Regular.otf) format("opentype");
}
```

Comment: You can have multiple web.config files, as well as individually control location specific settings for you "assets" folder. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/aspnet/application-directory-configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned throughout the post, **removing cache-control and pragma headers certainly fixes the issue**. However I had certain requirements to keep these headers. While I didn't directly fix this issue, this is how it was resolved for me -

Our application is deployed to an Azure App Service that utilizes Azure Front Door. I believe front door overwrites some of the headers with its own, so when I deployed it to the environment with front door, the issue disappeared altogether.

I should also mention that I did try the `<location>` and `path` suggestions, but those did not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

**1. Why does the cache-control affect my fonts not loading?**

I find [a blog](https://romixch.wordpress.com/2014/10/03/font-face-not-working-with-internet-explorer-and-http-header-pragmano-cache/) which explains the issue detaily. I think the reason the author said in the blog makes sense:

> - IE requests the font from the server.
> - As soon as the server starts delivering the resource, IE closes the connection. Probably because it suddenly detects that it should get the resource from cache.
> - This behaviour apparently destroys the cache content. So IE can’t access the font.
> - IE tries to retrieve the next declared font but with the same wrong pattern.
> - At the end it all leads to no font and a messy web site.

**2. How can I get around this? Can I specify there to be no cache-control headers for just my assets folder?**

The workaround for the issue is just like what you find: Remove the `no-cache` header.

About specify different headers for different files, I think Alex's comment is right. You can also refer to the accepted answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195266/how-to-configure-static-content-cache-per-folder-and-extension-in-iis7) to use `<location>` element and `path` attribute in web.config to achieve what you want.